# Validating combinations of arguments in kwargs in python

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a python function called `download`, which may be used in two ways:

```
download(git='git@github.com:someone/somerepo.git', ...)
download(url='https://someurl/something.tar.gz', ...)
```

When providing `git` as keyword argument, other keyword arguments (optional or mandatory) can be provided, such as `commit`, `tag`, `branch`, etc.
When providing `url`, other keywords arguments can be provided that are different from that of `git`, such as `md5`, or not.

When programming the `download` function, is there a conventional way of specifying which combinations of keyword parameters are valid, or is there a library that helps achieving this? For instance I would like to be able to print a warning if I specify a `commit` argument when the `url` argument is used, or throw an exception if both `git` and `url` arguments are used.

For now what I have is this:

```
def download(**kwargs):
    if 'git' in kwargs:
        if 'url' in kwargs:
            # throw error
        _download_with_git(**kwargs)
    elif 'url' in kwargs:
        _download_with_url(**kwargs)
    else:
        # throw error
```

This solution may be fine for now but can become intractable for other functions that have more combinations of parameters. I could think of writing a decorator to generalize the schema but I was wondering if something already exists.

Comment: Why write `download` in the first place, instead of just requiring the correct scheme-specific function be called? Is `download(git=...)` really clearer than `download_with_git(...)`?

Comment: It's probably simpler all around for the caller to construct a correct scheme-specific function call than it is for them to throw disparate arguments into a generic `download`, only for `download` to have to make sense of them. The caller knows what they want: let them be precise instead of making `download` guess.

Comment: I have highly simplified my use-case. I agree that it would be simpler to just provide `dowload_with_git/url` if it was just like I presented it, but let's assume it's not :-)

Comment: Well, you asked for the Pythonic solution, and it's this: absent any compelling reason to do so, you *don't* write a function that does entirely different things based on its arguments. The extreme and commonly cited example of this is a function that does two different things based on the value of a Boolean argument, but the same reasoning applies to a function whose arguments are basically used in Boolean expressions to make similar "this or that" decisions. If the result is dictated by the presence of a `git` or `url` keyword argument, you can just as easily have two functions....

Comment: ... as the selection process only differs in syntax: supply the correct function name, or supply the correct keyword argument.

Comment: One context in which it is useful to have a single function is if that function is meant as a factory, for instance, and you got the parameters by parsing some json or yaml file. This is what's done for instance [here](https://github.com/spack/spack/blob/develop/lib/spack/spack/fetch_strategy.py#L1401) where the `from_kwargs` function will look at kwargs and at some attributes of some classes to instantiate the right class. This is the solution I'd go for, I was just wondering if some library exists that help with such a pattern.